# What is this piece at the end of refridgerator water dispenser line called?

Tags: refrigerator

Image is from [this video](https://youtu.be/tlhCczTTuD4?t=229) at 3:49. The piece attaches to both water dispenser lever (via screw) and water line (by inserting water line into this piece).

[image: piece at the end of refridgerator water dispenser line]

Comment: What's your model number and manufacturer?

Comment: That appears to be a custom or OEM discharge nipple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that same YouTube channel has a video on how to replace that part too, and they list the part number as WP4388152 "Water Tube Assembly".  There are a few parts sellers that seem to carry this, one being [here](https://partsdr.com/part/4388152-nozzle-tube-kit).

[Link to video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZTJKnTsGfs)